# Wrapping a fortran function in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, fortran, rstudio, rcpp

This initially appeared to me to be a simple task but I cannot get the following to work.  I am trying to wrap a fortran subroutine into a Rcpp call in order to have the function available in R to use.  The goal is to incorporate the function into a package so the idea of just using dyn.load() on the specific *.so file isn't feasible (unless someone can show me how?).  From reading similar posts I suspect specifying flags in the makevars file may solve the problem but the information provided is very terse [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars) and some clarification would be sincerely appreciated.

I have done the following as close to documentation as I could follow.

1. Create the package structure with `Rcpp.package.skeleton`
2. Place my fortran file (hello.f) in the src directory
3. Created a basic cpp file for the Rcpp wrapper (hello.cpp)
4. Create a R file to create a 'clean' function call (i.e. avoid the `.Call` for the user and allow for running other internal calculates prior to the `.Call`)

However, when I try and build my package (with RStudio), I get the following error output:

```
==> R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source fortran

g++ -shared -o fortran.so RcppExports.o hello.o hello.o rcpp_hello_world.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
* installing to library ‘/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
* installing *source* package ‘fortran’ ...
** libs
hello.o: In function `hello_wrapper':
/home/.../r_code/fortran/src/hello.cpp:16: multiple definition of `hello_wrapper'
hello.o:/home/.../r_code/fortran/src/hello.cpp:16: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [fortran.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fortran’
* removing ‘/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/fortran’

Exited with status 1.
```

My files are as follows:

**hello.f**

```
subroutine hello()
    print *, "hello world"
end subroutine hello
```

**hello.h**

```
extern "C"
{
  void hello();
}
```

**hello.cpp**

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>

#include "hello.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
  SEXP hello_wrapper();
}
#endif

SEXP
hello_wrapper ()
{
  hello();
}
```

**wrapper.R**

```
hello_r <- function(){
  .Call("hello_wrapper");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is as simple as R being unhappy when you include multiple files of the name name with different extensions. Try renaming `hello.f` to `hello_fortran.f` and going from there.

Comment: Yes, I was about to suggest that too.  Besides that it should be trivial.

Comment: This gets me closer after renaming `hello.f` to `hello_fortran.f` and `hello.cpp` to `hello_cpp.cpp` but now another error in `dyn.load... unable to load shared object /home/.../fortran.so: undefined symbol: hello`

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I have learned that the fortran function requires an underscore in the header and when called in the cpp file.  After doing this, the package builds successfully.  I will accept this answer as it solved my initial problem but thank you as well Dirk, I appreciate both of your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may work if you remove the

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
  SEXP hello_wrapper();
}
#endif
```

part.  Also look at the Rcpp Attributes vignette -- you don't need to write `wrapper.R` by hand.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however this didn't solve the problem.  I still have the error about 'multiple definition of `hello_wrapper()`'  I will look into the Rcpp attributes as well.

Comment: Also, are you aware of `.Fortran()` ?  You don't have to involve Rcpp in this.  But do need to / want to do some work at the C++ level before calling Fortran?

Comment: I am aware of `.Fortran()` but yes I would like to do some C++ before certain Fortran calls.  I have seen this done in other packages which I am trying to replicate with this simple program but get stuck with this error.

Comment: It certainly is doable and we should have an example. I couldn't think of one immediately but I'll get back to you on this.